# How to have multiple routes for retrieving same html content

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, ember-cli

I have 2 routes /main and /home. Both should show the same HTML content. Is it possible to point both the routes to the same hbs file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to point routes at the same hbs file, but this is what components are for

First, generating a component can be done via `ember g component my-content`

then in `app/routes/main.hbs`
You could define:

```
<MyContent />
```

and then in `app/routes/home.hbs`
You could define:

```
<MyContent />
```

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion by @NullVoxPopuli. (Only adding this because I can't seem to add Markdown in the comments for the answer above).

```markdown
app/
┣ components/
┃ ┗ my-content.hbs (the common HTML content)
┣ routes/
┃ ┣ home.ts
┃ ┗ main.js
┣ templates/
┃ ┣ home.hbs
┃ ┣ main.hbs
┣ ...
```

Components make your code highly reusable.